# MOSS 2007 to Sharepoint 2010 Preupgrade check

Tags: migration

My Current farm is Windows 2003 64 bit and MOSS 2007 64 bit SP3 and SQL Server 64 bit edition

Iam planning to do a database attach upgrade migration. I have a new farm created with Sharepoint 2010 installed with all the prerequisites

When i run the preupgrade tool in MOSS 2007 farm iam getting a Issue

Issue : Unsupported SQL Server or unresponsive database
The following SQL server(s) do not meet the minimal version requirement:
DataSource = Server\SHAREPOINT, Version = 9.0.3042.0, 64-bit Edition = Yes, Express Edition = No

Since iam going ahead with Database attach approach . Will the above issue matters?

Answer (score 1):

As long as you're not going to use that database server with SharePoint 2010 you can ignore the message.

Your SQL server is SQL Server 2005 SP2 and the minimum for SP2010 is SP3 with CU3

Answer (score 0):

After attaching the databases to the new database server, and before mounting the content database in your new farm, be sure to run the Test-SPContentDatabase powershell command to ensure that there are no pre-upgrade issues or dependencies that need to be resolved that could otherwise lead to a failed upgrade.  While the pre-upgrade check is helpful, I ultimately find the Test-SPContentDatabase much more relevant since it is more complete and also looks for any possible missing solutions that were still installed on the source farm.

Here is the technet link for the Test-SPContentDatabase command:  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607941.aspx